# Acess first line via pandas.read_csv, when header is set to 1

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the case of a csv file with first row as units and second row as headers. I want to import the header as header, to conviniently use the parse_dates function of pd.read_csv. So I need to set the header equal to 1. Sadly, pandas seems to drop the first row. Is there a way to use both functions - **header**, as well as **parse_dates** - to **keep the first row** with units and **without reading the .csv twice**?
*Code Example*:

```
import pandas as pd
dict = {"-": ["A","2022-01-27 12:15:32.005","2022-01-27 12:15:33.005","2022-01-27 12:15:34.005"], "s": ["B",3,2,1], "W": ["C",2,3,1]}
csv = pd.DataFrame(dict).to_csv("test.csv")
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", header = 1, parse_dates = ["A"])
```

Comment: What's wrong with reading only the first line with one `read_csv` call, then reading the remaining lines with a second?

Comment: Datasets are really long and I want to keep the script efficient. Maybe I have overseen something, but doesn't pandas always read the whole thing first? I do not want to read the file twice...

Comment: There's an `nrows` parameter in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html): "Number of rows of file to read. Useful for reading pieces of large files."

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will solve it for now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can read several rows as a multilevel headers by passing a list of row numbers, where the header lines are located.

Here's a model:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

some_file = StringIO()    # just to avoid messing on a disk

dict = {
    "-": ["A","2022-01-27 12:15:32.005","2022-01-27 12:15:33.005","2022-01-27 12:15:34.005"], 
    "s": ["B",3,2,1], 
    "W": ["C",2,3,1]
}

# here I drop index with index=False, 
# otherwise I'd pass index_col=1 to pd.read_csv
pd.DataFrame(dict).to_csv(some_file, index=False)

some_file.seek(0)    # let's read the file from the start

# with header=[0,1] we read the first two rows as a multiheader
# to parse dates we could use also parse_dates=[0]
df = pd.read_csv(some_file, header=[0,1], parse_dates=[('-','A')])
print(df, df.dtypes, sep='\n\n')
```

Output:

```
                        -  s  W
                        A  B  C
0 2022-01-27 12:15:32.005  3  2
1 2022-01-27 12:15:33.005  2  3
2 2022-01-27 12:15:34.005  1  1

-  A    datetime64[ns]
s  B             int64
W  C             int64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure, but i think this code could be helpful for you.

`df = pd.read_csv("test.csv",skiprows=[1],names =["A","B","C"],parse_dates=['A'])`

output:

```
                         A  B  C
0                        -  s  W
1  2022-01-27 12:15:32.005  3  2
2  2022-01-27 12:15:33.005  2  3
3  2022-01-27 12:15:34.005  1  1
```

Comment: Check the type of the first column if it's a datetime